# How to add all source files in a folder, except for specific files?

Tags: cmake

I have a folder full of source files (*.h, *.cpp), that I want to include in a new project. However, the folder also contains two files (main.cpp, CMakeLists.txt) that I don't want to include in the new project (for obvious reasons).

I know that the commands:

```
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
```

add all the source files in the project directory to the project. Also I could say:

```
aux_source_directory(/path/to/folder/ SRC_LIST)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
```

to include all source files in a folder. But how can I exclude some specific files (in this example, `/path/to/folder/main.cpp` and `/path/to/folder/CMakeLists.txt`)?

Comment: I would recommend against doing this for a variety of reasons that have been discussed before, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18538444/393701

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But how can I exclude some specific files

Try this (according to [Documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/list.html)):

```
list (REMOVE_ITEM SRC_LIST /path/to/folder/main.cpp /path/to/folder/CMakeLists.txt)
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114680/removing-files-from-a-set) looks like related.