# CMake add_subdirectory in subdirectory not included

Tags: cmake

I have a directory tree like this:

```
libs
   support
       db
          csv
       patterns
   support_qt
       helpers
       dialogs
```

etc.

Now when I do the `add_subdirectory` in the `support` level, I can add `db` and `patterns` and the files are collected. However in `db` I added another `add_subdirectory` referencing the `csv`, but somehow this is ignored.

In `support`

```
set(SUPPORT_SOURCE
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/support_defs.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/support_dll_api.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/supportlib_namespace.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dll_main.cpp
)

add_subdirectory (db)
add_subdirectory (patterns)
```

In `db`

```
set(SUPPORT_SOURCE ${SUPPORT_SOURCE}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/column_types.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dbcolumn.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/database_login.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/database_login.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/type_helper.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/type_helper.cpp

    PARENT_SCOPE
)

add_subdirectory(csv)
```

The above works fine but in `csv`

```
set(SUPPORT_SOURCE ${SUPPORT_SOURCE}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/csv.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/csv.cpp

    PARENT_SCOPE
)
```

But these files are not included in the build. So do I have to put the add_subdirectory calls all into the root file?

Comment: The PARENT_SCOPE goes only one level up. I think you are better off with a CACHE INTERNAL, global variable, like this `set(SUPPORT_SOURCE ${SUPPORT_SOURCE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dbcolumn.h [...] CACHE INTERNAL "")` But I am not sure how it works with a variable set multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution. I have to put the `add_subdirectory` before the `set` command.

```
add_subdirectory(csv)
set(SUPPORT_SOURCE ${SUPPORT_SOURCE}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/column_types.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dbcolumn.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/database_login.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/database_login.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/type_helper.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/type_helper.cpp

    PARENT_SCOPE
)
```

Comment: For big projects, it's usually fine to use globbing expressions.

Comment: But with globbing it would also find generated files, right? Also I have some files which are not included in the lib, but are still in that directory tree.

Comment: @Antonio I personally avoid globbing, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18538444/678093

Comment: @m.s. Globbing saves a lot of tedious and uninformative cmake code. It has to be done carefully though, on this I agree. For example, we use git hooks to trigger cmake to run at the next build after pulling from the repository. Let's link also [the other, more popular, answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1060061/2436175) :)

Comment: @Devolus Sure, it will find anything your globbing expression matches. You can decide to have a very wide globbing expression, and exclude the rare extra files (there are plenty of Q/A in this sense: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16449676/2436175 http://stackoverflow.com/q/15550777/2436175 http://stackoverflow.com/q/13114680/2436175). Or you can use a more specific globbing function to get only get the files/directories you need.